# Pagination in django

Tags: python, django

I wanted to implement pagination in my django based app. For that I am using django-pagination module. However the pagination generated by it is not pleasing. I wanted something like the one generated by django's admin view where the page numbers are clickable links rather than something like Page 1 of 4 next... Suggestions?. It should have been possible since django's admin view is generating it.

Comment: you can modify the template of django-pagination to django admin pagination page!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change the template. The one as an example [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view) is not the default. You can do anything else with the paginator integrated attributes and functions.